# Suggestions Needed For One-Time-Password Generator/Verification Software

Tags: open-source, programming, authentication

I have a project that requires the use of OTP to verify users registering to the system. They'd like to be able to collect a registrant's phone number, generate an OTP which would be sent to the phone in some manner, and have the registrant enter the OTP during registration for verification. I wonder if there is any standalone OTP package out there (commercial or open-source) that can be used to accomplish the generation and verification easily with CRUD?

The software should work preferably on Linux, in a web server, or at least be easily able to make requests against it for both generation and verification.

**Some background:**

The users wont interact with the system at all. I am envisioning other systems interacting with the software, which are what the users would have access to. For example a web registration system needing to verify registrants phone numbers could interact with the OTP software to produce an OTP string, and when the user sends back the OTP string to the registration system, the registration system can check with the OTP software to verify the string. The registration system should be able to send REST calls to the OTP software for all this.

Thanks for the assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio has a service that may be able to help called [Authy](https://www.twilio.com/authy)